# Unable to access TextBox in WP7 code

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have my xaml as following

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="firstBlock"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

problem is that i cant use TextBlock in code. it gives error

**The name 'firstBlock' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using it as a part of DataTemplate.

Why not just use it like this:

```
<Button Name="btn">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock x:Name="firstBlock"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Or if it's just the TextBlock you need in your button, just call

btn.Content = "some text";